# Kotlin force nullable generic type into a non-nullable of the same generic type?

Tags: generics, kotlin

First of all I just want to point out that I'm aware of the [Force a null into non-nullable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693385/force-a-null-into-non-nullable-type) and [Kotlin Generics and nullable Class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100656/kotlin-generics-and-nullable-class-type) but I don't think these questions are the same as mine (correct me if I'm wrong).

**Background**

I'm developing a library called [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org) which, simply put, is designed to wait until a predicate evaluates to true. The [Kotlin API](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/blob/master/awaitility-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/org/awaitility/kotlin/AwaitilityKt.kt) provides a way to write expressions like this:

```
// Create a simple data class example
data class Data(var value: String)
// A fake repository that returns a possibly nullable instance of Data
interface DataRepository {
    // Invoked from other thread
    fun loadData() : Data?
} 
val dataRepository = .. // Implementation of DataRepository

// Now Awaitility allows you to wait until the "value" in Data is equal to "Something"
val data : Data = await untilCallTo { dataRepository.loadData() } has {
    value == "Something"
}
```

This works because `has` returns `false` if `dataRepository.loadData()` returns `null` and never calls the supplied receiver function (`{ value == "Something" }`) if `data` is `null`. Awaitility will also throw an exception if the condition is not satisfied so we *know* that what's returned from the expression has type `Data` (and not `Data?`) as you can see in the example.

The `has` function is implemented like this:

```
infix fun <T> AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<T?>.has(pred: T.() -> Boolean) = factory.until(fn) { t: T? ->
    if (t == null) {
        false
    } else {
        pred(t)
    }
} as T
```

where `AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition` looks like this:

```
data class AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<T> internal constructor(internal val factory: ConditionFactory, internal val fn: () -> T?)
```

(you can also find the ConditionFactory [here](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/blob/master/awaitility/src/main/java/org/awaitility/core/ConditionFactory.java) if needed)

While the example above works great when the lambda passed to `untilCallTo` returns a nullable type (`Data?`) it doesn't compile if we pass it a non-nullable type (i.e. `Data`). For example if we simply modify the repository to look like this:

```
interface DataRepository {
    // Invoked from other thread
    fun loadData() : Data // Notice that loadData now returns a non-nullable type
}
```

and if we then try the same Awaitility expression as in the previous example:

```
val data : Data = await untilCallTo { dataRepository.loadData() } has {
    value == "Something"
}
```

we'll get a compile-time error:

```
Error:(160, 20) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<Data> but AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<Data?> was expected
Error:(160, 68) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Please try to specify type arguments explicitly.
```

Which is (of course) correct!

**Question**

What I want to do is to somehow modify the `has` method to force the return type to always be the non-nullable equivalent of the type that's passed in as argument (which can be either nullable or non-nullable). I've tried to do something like this (which doesn't work):

```
infix fun <T, T2> AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<T>.has(pred: T2.() -> Boolean): T2
        where T : Any?, // Any? is not required but added for clarity
              T2 : T!! // This doesn't compile
        = factory.until(fn) { t: T ->
                if (t == null) {
                    false
                } else {
                    pred(t as T2)
                }
} as T2
```

This doesn't compile due to `T2 : T!!` but I hope that it shows my intention. I.e. I want to somehow define `T2` as:

1. The non-nullable equivalent of type `T` if `T` is nullable
2. To be the same as `T` if `T` is a non-nullable type

Is this possible in Kotlin?

Update:

I've created a branch in the Awaitility project called `has-with-non-nullable-type` where you get the compile-time error I'm talking about in the file [KotlinTest](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/blob/has-with-non-nullable-type/awaitility-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/org/awaitility/kotlin/KotlinTest.kt#L160). This is what I want to make compile. You can clone it using:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility.git
```

Update 2:

I've added [gist](https://gist.github.com/johanhaleby/c230e21d086aecdf1ef76f2f397b1f17) that I think demonstrates the problem without using any dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition` can be made [contravariant (so `AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<T>` is a subtype of `AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<T?>`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html), and this modification of your gist seems to satisfy the requirements:

```
// Fake Awaitility DSL
data class AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<out T>(val factory: ConditionFactory, val fn: () -> T)

infix fun <T : Any> AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<T?>.has(pred: T.() -> Boolean): T = factory.until(fn) { t: T? ->
    if (t == null) {
        false
    } else {
        pred(t)
    }
}!!

class ConditionFactory {
    fun <T : Any?> until(supplier: () -> T, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T {
        val result = supplier()
        return if (predicate(result)) {
            result
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Supplied value is not matching predicate")
        }
    }
}

class Await {
    infix fun <T> untilCallTo(supplier: () -> T): AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition<T> {
        val conditionFactory = ConditionFactory()
        return AwaitilityKtUntilFunCondition(conditionFactory, supplier)
    }
}

// Example

data class Data(var state: String)
interface DataRepository<T> {
    fun loadData(): T
}

val nullableDataRepository: DataRepository<Data?> = TODO()
val nonNullableDataRepository: DataRepository<Data> = TODO()


// Both of these compile
val data1: Data = Await() untilCallTo { nonNullableDataRepository.loadData() } has {
    state == "something"
}

val data2: Data = Await() untilCallTo { nullableDataRepository.loadData() } has {
    state == "something"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I created a minimal example which achieves what you want:

```
fun <T: Any> test(t: T?): T {
    // ...
    return t as T
}
```

You define an upper bound `Any` for `T` so it cannot be `null`. For the parameter `t` you use the type `T?`. In the end you return `t` casted to `T`.

**Examples:**

```
val a: String = test("Hello")
val b: String = test(null)
```

Comment: I hear you but it doesn't solve my actual problem in Awaitility when I try to do this. I don't know if the question should be clearer or if it's even misplaced. I know it's much to ask but I've added instructions on how to clone the project and created a new branch that shows the problem exactly if you're up for it.

Comment: @Johan what exactly is the problem with this? This should work, but requires you to place `T?` and `T` in the right places

Comment: @Zoe Well the problem is that if I try what Willi suggests it doesn't make [my code](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/blob/has-with-non-nullable-type/awaitility-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/org/awaitility/kotlin/KotlinTest.kt#L160) compile which is what I want.

Comment: Btw, I'm very happy for improvement suggestions to my question. I've tried to be as clear as I can but I'm sure the that it can be improved.

Comment: @Johann create a minimal self-contained example (no dependencies ) which shows exactly what does not work with the concept explained in my answer. Only this way we can narrow down the problem. I think the problem is really interesting :)

Comment: @WilliMentzel I've created a gist now that I think covers what I'm asking: https://gist.github.com/johanhaleby/c230e21d086aecdf1ef76f2f397b1f17